# Magento - Please specify the product required option(s) Error

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, cart, custom-options

I got a problem using Magento about add to cart with custom options.

I filled up all required fields and when I hit "Add To Cart" button, It said

> Please specify the product required option(s).

When I go to other products without custom options like Size or Color field. It works fine.

How can I fix this problem?

this is the link: https://francesandalbert.com/ring.html

Thanks.

Comment: Options are not submitted (what is not really the case if you ask me), id is wrong (5), value is wrong (7), or there are more options on the products which might not be visible in frontend?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you can solve this but I can explain the problem, maybe it helps.

I see that the product page is on `https` but when you click on the add to cart button the form is submitted to `http://francesandalbert.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2ZyYW5jZXNhbmRhbGJlcnQuY29tL3JpbmcuaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/product/172/`. Notice the `http`.

Then that pages does a 301 redirect to `https://{same url}` and what you send by post (the ring size) is lost.

If I use firebug and change the form url to `https` I can add the product to the cart without any problems.

You can try to change the submit url of the form `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract::getSubmitUrl` or you can set the unsecure base url of your website to `https://...` avoiding 301 redirects from htaccess.

These are just my suggestions. I have no idea if they will work.

Comment: It works. Thank you so much Marius.

I go to app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php

And I changed the getAddToCartUrl function

from:
 return $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional);

to:
 $new_url = str_replace('http://','https://',$this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, $additional));
 return $new_url;

Comment: @Enalds. I don't know if this is the cleanest solution but..."whatever floats your boat".

Comment: @Enalds change the unsecure url to https, your solution will bring you problems when you update!

Comment: @Fabian Blechschmidt - How can I change the unsecure url to https? I'm newbie to Magento :)

Comment: I also add array('_secure' => true) to the <form action=...

Comment: https://docs.nexcess.net/article/changing-magento-base-urls.html

Comment: @Marius I am getting the same error on magento v-1.7 but on only one store, i have two store setup and i don't get this error on both stores but only on one store. Can you please advise me something?
i am using different themes for both stores but when i set default theme to the store i am getting error on, still getting this.

Comment: @Saddam. I cannot guess what's wrong with your website. Try to see what's sent via post and debug step by step.

Comment: thanks @Marius for your quick response. i printed the posted data in cartController and there it doesn't have the required options data, mean the data is lost before going to cart controller. it mean some third party module is causing this error but our setting for both store are same and couldn't figure out why this issue is occurring on only one store.

Comment: You're a star bro!

Answer (score 0):

Check your ADD TO CART button code.

It should be:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
    <span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span>
</button>
```

or

app/design/frontend/default/*<your theme name>*/template/catalog/product/view and remove or rename `addtocart.phtml`.